# how to parse a date with strptime when zone is optional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have datetime string in the format `"1/4/2013 3:39:41 PM"` and I am using the following code `DateTime.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')` and it works.

But the problem is when the time is in AM, the input string does not have 'AM' present. So the string is like `"1/4/2013 3:39:41"` when referring to AM. And in these cases my code for parsing date throws error

```
ArgumentError: invalid date
    from (irb):45:in `strptime'
```

How can I make the `%p` optional in my template?

thanks

Comment: You could work around it by either adding AM if it doesn't exist or checking for the existence of AM/PM and using a different time format if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but you can continue:

```
if s.split(' ').size == 3
   format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'
// you can implement further variations here...    
else 
   format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'

DateTime.strptime(s, format)
```